# Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established when attach to running container -Docker remote container

Tags: docker

I use remote container in vscode to attach project to running container. But i received error bellow:

```
[4891 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[125054 ms] Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
        at connResetException (internal/errors.js:570:14)
        at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1361:19)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:228:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
```

When i create remote container via devcontainer.json also gave this error. How to fix it

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, i need to config proxy authen for vscode in setting.

Comment: Can you please add the steps to resolve this issue and solution would be helpful